# Can a Kindred Revenant breed with a Kuei-jin Dhamphyr?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, kindred-of-the-east

I'm writing a story that has this background: Malkavian Methuselah Seer sees the Modern Nights and the fate of his sister, who was embraced by the Ravnos clan, and decides to mix up things up to alter that future. With the help of said sister, he makes a breeding program to create a what he calls a Clan-Seed. They join the Sabbat for this secret purpose alone.

Male Malkavian Revenant and Female Ravnos Revenant make the maternal grandmother

Female Malkavian Revenant and Male Ravnos revenant make the maternal grandfather

Male Malkavian Revenant and captured kuei-jin Dhamphyr make the paternal grandmother

Same kuei-jin Dhamphyr and Male Ravnos Revenant make paternal grandfather

The Ravnos Sister blood-bonds the Son while The Malkavian Seer does the same, with the Daughter before having them breed the the new family. For centuries, the family grows, with the occasional new Ravnos or Malkavian ghoul added to the bloodline.

After 300 years, Caine himself meets the Siblings and they make a faustian Deal with him, and the Dark Father adds his own ghouls and revenants to the bloodline and another Cathayan Dhamphyr is captured for the bloodline.

Something big happens, and the Sabbat Cell is wiped out along with most of the Siblings' revenant family save for a few dozen that survive and scatter to the winds. The Siblings separate; the Malkavian Seer waits within the ranks of the Camarilla and the Ravnos Sister enters Torpor and remains hidden.

Three years after the wipeout, my character is born—the youngest of three—and in 2004 enters the unlife.

---

As you can see, I put A LOT of thought to this, and I really don't want it to go to waste. So, to VTM experts out there, is any or all of this *possible* or am I going to have to say screw it and pull creative license out somewhere?

Comment: Hi, Bonnie, welcome to the site. Please consider that people here like well written questions and answers. I'm not a good example, because as a non native writer, I commit tons of grammar mistakes, but please put some care on how you write, for instance, capitalizing the first letter of your sentences.

Answer (score 16):

## You can't breed with Dhampyrs

A dhampyr can only have childs with regular humans. They can't even breed between them. Plus, the child of a dhampyr is a completely normal human, only with a strange luck, that's it.

*(Half-Damned: Dhampyrs chapter 2.)*

## One generation up

But if you go to the father or mother of that dhampyr, that is, of the Kuei-jin that spawned them, you can breed it. Yang imbalanced Cathayans can have childs with almost every living or semiliving humanoid thing.

Unfortunately, the half-damned nature overrides every other herritage, so the child will be just a regular dhampyr (nothing is said about the grandsons, though).

*(Again, Half-Damned: Dhampyrs chapter 2.)*

## About Revenants

I'm not sure what you mean with a Ravnos Revenant and a Malkavian Revenant. Revenants are like born ghouls that belong to a Revenant Family. It takes centuries of ghouling and inbreeding to create a Revenant Family.

So, if the plan includes creating two separates Revenant Families, the plan must start many, many time before.

## The pattern

As you see, White Wolf seemed to put much effort in avoiding the kind of stories and characters you want to write. In nearly all cases, mixing supernatural types just don't work.

They give a lot of mystical, physiologic and metaphysic reasons for each case, but the design objective behind that is to avoid create a world populated by überpowerful hybrids with bizarre stories behind. The world should be populated by normal supernatural creatures, not their hybrids. The other reason is to avoid powergamers wanting to mix two, three or more supernatural types to create unbalanced characters.

## But you have Caine in your side

On the other hand, you have Caine appearing on your story. Caine might be a nearly omnipotent being, capable of sorcery that would allow you to do almost everything you want to do. Why couldn't the power of his blood allow to transfer the dhampiric qualities to the Revenant Families.

Seriously, if you don't care about Caine himself appearing to bless and improve the family, why care about what the books say about those breedings, and the limitations White Wolf stablished?

## Ask your Storyteller

At the end of the day, it's your Storyteller, not White Wolf, not us, who have final world on the viability of your story. If he's OK with hybrid creations, and with stilted stories, you can go away with it. On the other hand, if he dislikes them, even if the books supported it, he can forbid them, because he sets the tone of the story.

So, go and ask him. He is the ultimate responsible of the themes and ambient of the story.

## Consider making a more "natural" character

As a final advice, I won't recommend you to go for the bizarre. If every player is going for such a strange backstory as yours, you will have the ambient of a freak show.

I always encourage my players to create normal characters. A family father, a brilliant but burned businesswoman, an idealist or a corrupt cop, can make characters as dramatic and interesting as one of the last descendants of a supernatural freak artificial family. And they mess less with the setting, the Storyteller ideas, and your character **progression**.

I highlighted the word **"progression"** because that's the important thing of a character. He needs space to grow. And bizarre characters have their possibilities more constrained. If the chronicle lasts years, your character will feel weirder and weirder, and the strange story will be a weight you will have to support.

Don't put all the cool before the chronicle starts, be a normal guy and let the cool come.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the last few paragraphs twice.

Comment: @DvdZee That's why I put a 500 point bounty on it. That's like... 50 up-vote-equivalents. :)

Comment: wow, I almost fell off the chair when I saw I had +520. Thanks @T.J.L.